# Multiple Threads starting a Transaction within JUNIT

Tags: multithreading, transactions, junit, entitymanager

I am trying to reproduce (and not fullproof test the multithreading issue) the thread block issue in one of my methods by writing a unit test. Since I see plenty of instances of

```
org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute update query
```

in our 2 server PROD environment, I should be able to reproduce fairly easily in my unit test.
I tried to spawn multiple threads within my JUnit method and each thread invoking my method. I tried with 2 threads to begin with.

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        exec.execute(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 System.out.println("who is running: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
                 em.getTransaction().begin();
                //do something()
                 em.getTransaction().commit();
             }
        });
    }
```

I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-2" who is running: 11
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction already active
at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:35)
```

It is not letting me create Transaction for the second thread with an error 'Transaction is already Active'. I thought EntityManager  could have multiple Active Threads present at any given time ( and hence a singleton entitymanager)?

Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

EntityManager is not thread-safe. That's why it is often told that you should not inject EntityManager to shared instances like Servlets. It is clearly documented (JSR-317 page 286):

> An entity manager must not be shared among multiple concurrently
>   executing threads, as the entity manager and persistence context are
>   not required to be threadsafe. Entity managers must only be accessed
>   in a single-threaded manner.

Comment: I tried creating multiple EntityManagers and associating them for each Thread but I still encounter 'Thread is already active' after 1st thread creates an active Tx.